# How to set a proper connection string for Azure database?

Tags: asp.net, azure, connection-string

I have an azure website and database. I'm running an ASP.NET MVC 4 / EF 5 app localy and trying to put some data to the azure database before to deploy the app. But I have a TargetInvocationException : {"The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588"}
Keyword not supported : server

This is the connection string that I get from my azure dashboard :

```
    <add name="myconstring" connectionString=Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydatabase;User ID=cdptest@myserver;Password=******;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I tried this I got "Keyword not supported : data source"

```
    <add name="myconstring" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.database.windows.net;Initilal Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=cdptest@myserver;Password=*****;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: the db is exisiting? are you running the page in azure? did you enable the firewall rules for either azure or your premise?

Comment: the db exists of course, I can browse it with SSMS or Visual Studio explorer. I added rules to allow my IPs to connect to the db. I'm running the app on my local environment (from Visual Studio)

Comment: your are missing `"` around your connectionString variable.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
 <add name="coupdpoAPEkowswAEntities" connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydatabase;User ID=cdptest@myserver;Password=*****;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Use Server instead of Data Source, and specify the protocol and the port, and use Database instead of Initial Catalog

Comment: this is exactly what I did first and I had the following error "Keyword not supported : server".

Answer (score 0):

OK the providername was wrong. System.Data.SqlClient was excepted as this is a code first app model.
I probably got System.Data.EntityClient from another app with Model First or Database First...