# On azure web APi show 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud

I have developed a web api project in visual studio 2013 update 4 with EF6 in windows 8.1 pro pc and here is my connection string generated by EF

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="bcsmdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BCSMModel.csdl|res://*/BCSMModel.ssdl|res://*/BCSMModel.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=j01qw1lha2.database.windows.net;
     initial catalog=bcsmdb;persist security info=True;user id=xxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

when I am performing GET request its working fine in my local machine but after deploy it in azure as web app its return 500 internal server error. The error details are like this

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "The underlying provider failed on Open.",
"ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n
```

Can anyone please help me to find out what is going wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: check if the address of database server is correct and it is reachable

Comment: previously it was working fine, I have used everything like this several times, but when I have changed the Entity model with new database its acting like this, for information I am co admin of the azure account where the database is and deployed the web app

Comment: try to point to a new database and check.

Comment: Yes I have tried using new database and new region but same result

Comment: can you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017705/how-to-set-a-proper-connection-string-for-azure-database

Answer (score -1):

I have found the problem, it was actually the azure administrator right problem, problem fixed