# after deploying web api to azure every call from the api to the class library fails

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

i deployed my class library to azure.
the api has a class library as a dependency, when i work locally with iis everything works.
the problam is when i deployed the api to azure, every call to the api thet makes the api use the class library fails (status code 500) , when i make a call to the api and it has nothing to do with the class library it works but for some resone i cant call the use the class library from the api in azure.
i have tried to set the copy local veribal to true but could not find where it is (if thet is relevent)
thenks in advence for your help!.

Comment: 500 means server side error. Find the error either in logs or debugging or whatever but you need to debug the server side deployed code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#500-internal-server-error)

> **Getting 500 internal server error**
> The app starts, but an error prevents the server from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error occurs within the app's code during startup or while
> creating a response. The response may contain no content, or the
> response may appear as a  *500 Internal Server Error*  in the browser.
> The Application Event Log usually states that the app started
> normally. From the server's perspective, that's correct. The app did
> start, but it can't generate a valid response. Run the app at a
> command prompt on the server or enable the ASP. NET Core Module stdout
> log to troubleshoot the problem.

Please refer the links for more information [On azure web APi show 500 internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900667/on-azure-web-api-show-500-internal-server-error)  ,  [How to resolve error 500 on Azure web app | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967675/how-to-resolve-error-500-on-azure-web-app/49267536) and [500 internal server error on web app| MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/359043/500-internal-server-error-on-web-app.html)